# ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow occurs when trying to return relevant values using devise token auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, devise, devise-token-auth

## Assumption

I'm using `devise token auth` in Rails, and when I try to return values related to user information created with `devise token auth`, I get a `cookie over capacity` error. If I use `model name.all` the error does not occur.
How can I resolve this error?

## What we want to solve

- I want to resolve a `ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow` error and return the value associated with `user` created with `devise token auth`.

## Code

Controller

```rb
class Api::V1::PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    # posts = Post.all
    posts = current_api_v1_user.posts  # ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow

    render json: posts, status: :ok
  end
```

## Error

```
api_1    | ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow (ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow):
```

## I tried

- The only thing I could come up with in my research was to use `activerecord-session_store` gem, but I guess I was wrong and the error was not resolved.

**gem**

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.6'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
・
・
・

AJAX possible
gem 'rack-cors'

gem 'active_model_serializers'

# JWT Doc: https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt
gem 'jwt', '~> 2.2'

gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_token_auth'
gem 'activerecord-session_store'　# Add
```

**Migaration**

```rb
class AddSessionsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :sessions do |t|
      t.string :session_id, :null => false
      t.text :data
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :sessions, :session_id, :unique => true
    add_index :sessions, :updated_at
  end
end
```

**config/initializers/session_store.rb**

```rb
Rails.application.config.session_store :active_record_store,:key => '_my_app_session'
```

Comment: Don't see any code that sets a cookie.

Comment: @dbugger  Thanks for your comment, I would love to know if you have any articles or other information on cookie settings.

Comment: Any clues here? https://daniel.fone.net.nz/blog/2014/11/28/actiondispatch-cookies-cookieoverflow-via-devise-s-user-return-to/